# Set a default (select) option in combination with ngModel

Tags: html, angular, typescript, 2-way-object-databinding

I have component which includes a select.

the options are set with an @Input and bind witn ngModel.
However I can not set the default with this combination.

My component:

```
export class someComponent {
  @input() options: any[];
  @Input() selectedOption: any;
  @Output() optionChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onOptionChanged() {
    this.optionChanged.emit(this.selectedOption);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select *ngIf="options" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" (change)="onOptionChange_select(selectedOption)">
  <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.text">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

afterviewInit did not work and also set the value of the first option did not work for me.

The first option is not binded

I would like to set the first option selected when loaded. With this code none of the options is selected when the component is loaded.

the options input is like:

[{id: '1', text: 'option1'}, {id: '2', text: 'option2'}]

Comment: You are selected by default "Select an option" Please remove selected default then check I think it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `ngOnChanges`, this will default the value every time value changes in Parent.

```
ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges){
  if(change['options']){
     this.selectedOption = 'Select an option';
   }
 }
```

Or use ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.selectedOption = 'Select an option';
}
```

Comment: The default / first option is not in the options array as you can see in the html
I have tried to pass the value from it's parent. Idid not work.

Comment: Updated my answer, In this case u don't need to use ngOnChages, ngOnInit will also work fine.

Comment: I also needed to change value to ngValue to pass an object. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have selected by default **"Select an option"**.

```
<option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
```

Please remove this selected property or add the condition on this like

```
<option [selected]="!selectedOption" disabled>Select an option</option>
```

Comment: selected will be changed /removed when you select another option.The 'ngModel' will not be updated with this change